# What is the reason of blue pixels (noise) on screen?

Tags: graphics

My problem is, that if I play a game the screen gets blue noise pixels. If i reboot, even the bios prompt is not only black but with some blue pixels dancing around.

What could be the origin of this behaviour?

Please post your solutions to a problem like this. Maybe it will provide guidance to some other people with similar problems.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, this is almost always caused by the the GPU not making proper contact with the traces on the video card board. The most common cause is cracking of the bump underfill material where it meets the package solder balls. If the card is still under warranty, get it repaired.

If this is the issue, it will be worst when the card is cold as less serious when the card is hot -- particularly when you first start having problems. It will tend to get worse over time too.

Comment: Thats not the answer I wanted to hear ;-) *away returning GPU*

Comment: I'd say the problem is heat-related, but the other way around. Since playing a game causes the problem, and games stress videocards more heavily, I conclude that it's worst if the card is hot.

Comment: I'll check if it occurs only if I play. Last time it happend as soon as I started the game and the pc was only started minutes ago.

Comment: This also happens if there's something plain wrong with the GPU (usually the onboard RAM).  It's probably thermal stress related drift, though, as Dave mentions.  (It isn't necessarily only when cold, either.)

Comment: If it's worse if the card is hot, then it's not bump underfill cracking. With bump underfill cracking, thermal expansion causes the parts to make better contact. Sometimes it fails so badly that the problem happens at all times, but if it gets worse with heat, it's not underfill cracking.

Comment: I changed the primary display and it disappeared, so it seemed to be a display issue.

Comment: You mean you changed to a different monitor? Or you changed the driver? Or you changed which port you were using?

Comment: I have two monitors and changed the ports. Monitor 1 is now 2 and vice versa. Now the gaming happens on the other monitor and the problem is gone. Maybe it was a cable issue and the cables are making proper contact now.

Comment: I hope so. It's still quite possible it's a GPU issue that's only affecting the link to one monitor, but I'm not really sure. I haven't seen anyone else report a problem that was solved that way.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by switching the monitors, so monitor 1 is now 2.

Maybe it was a cable issue and now it makes proper contact now.

Answer (score 0):

This is a really simple one. If you have an external monitor, the HDMI cord might not be plugged in all the way. Had the same problem and it worked for me. Check that before getting a warranty and stuff!

Comment: 11 years ago it is unlikely this was due to an HDMI cable. Most computer monitors used VGA or DVI as their connector.